# Kafka Zookeeper Security Authentication & Authorization(JAAS) Using SASL

Tags: security, authentication, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, sasl

Regarding Kafka-Zookeeper Security using DIGEST MD5 Authentication, I am trying to rotate/change credentials/password for both server(zookeeper) and client(kafka) jaas config file.
We have a 3 node cluster of 3 zookeepers and 3 kafka broker nodes with below jaas configuration file.

kafka.conf

```
org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
username="super"
password="password";
};
```

zookeeper.conf

```
Server {
org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
user_super="password";
};
```

To rotate we do a rolling restart of server(zookeeper) instances after updating the credential(password) and during the process of rolling restart after updating the same credential/password for `super` user for client(kafka instances) one at a time, we notice

```
[2019-06-15 17:17:38,929] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-06-15 17:17:38,929] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
```

these info level in server logs, which eventually results in unclean shutdown and restart of the broker which impacts the writes and reads for longer than expected. I have tried commenting `requireClientAuthScheme=sasl` in zookeeper zoo.cfg https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Client-Server+mutual+authentication to allow any clients authenticate to zookeeper but no success.

Also, alternative approach - tried to update the credential/password in jaas config file dynamically using `sasl.jaas.config`  and do get the same exception documented in this jira (reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8010).
can someone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.